# Hacklang - Search Map by value

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

G'day

While in strict mode, is there a way to search a Map via value rather than key?

Say I have a Map:

```
$temp = Map{'melon', 'apple'};
```

How could I search via value?

Answer (score 1):

First, the Map in your example isn't a valid Map. Maps in Hack are key-value pairs, and you only provided keys. I assume this is a typo, and the example you meant to give was something like

```
$temp = Map {'fruit' => 'apple', 'veg' => 'carrot'};
```

To search a map in Hack, you can do the same thing you would in PHP: iterate over it in an O(n) scan. Here's an example function that does so, written with Hack generics so it will have the right type no matter the input Map.

```
function find_key<Tk, Tv>(Map<Tk, Tv> $haystack, Tv $needle): ?Tk {
  foreach ($haystack as $k => $v) {
    if ($v === $needle) {
      return $k;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

However, a final question back to you: why are you searching a Map like this? Maps were meant to have fast value lookup for a given key, as well as fast iteration over all key/value pairs. They are *not* designed for value lookup like this -- that's why it takes an O(n) loop, which should set off warning signs that what you're doing might not be the best. You may want to consider using a more appropriate data structure: maybe building an inverse map if you're doing this operation often, or using a Set or a Vector depending.

Comment: I was reading the docs and they said to use Maps as much as possible. I was not aware that Maps require a key-value pairs. I assumed they would add an element to the end of the object similar to how arrays work in php. The second question why. I have multiple arrays that are designed to be searched via value and if the value exists in one of these arrays, it is meant to return a constant.

I assumed perhaps Map had a function like "contain", but searchs on value not key.

Comment: Maps very deliberately do not behave like PHP arrays, in order to avoid the confusion of what exactly the semantics are supposed to mean that you see a lot in PHP arrays -- the behavior of `array_merge` exemplifies this complexity. That's why there's `Vector` and `Set`, which depending on *why* your Map is "designed to be searched by value" might be a better replacement. Searching a Map by value is almost never a good idea and indicative of bad design. Can you link me to the docs page that said to always use a Map, we should fix/clarify it.

Comment: I have misread the information, http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.arrays.php - Says: The Hack language guidance is to use collections whenever and wherever possible. Apologies. I had taken what was said out of context. I'll use "Sets" as they appear to be what I would like to use.